# Sequence of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, formatting, iteration, table

Let's say I have the following table,

```
y=40;
b=Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2.25, 1.25}, {j, y - 5, y - 8, -3}], 1]
```

then c is equal to,

```
c = b - ConstantArray[{0, 8}, 4]
```

and the out put is

```
{{1., 27}, {1., 24}, {2.25, 27}, {2.25, 24}}
```

y is 27 and 24 which is fine

d equal to

```
d = c - ConstantArray[{0, 8}, 4]
```

similarly, y is >=4, which is fine,

e equal to

```
e = d - ConstantArray[{0, 8}, 4]
```

again,  y is >=4, which is fine,

and f equal to

```
f = e - ConstantArray[{0, 8}, 4]
```

the output is

```
{{1., 3}, {1., 0}, {2.25, 3}, {2.25, 0}}
```

so now in f, y less than 4, so it is not fine,

How can I make a table using any iteration command such that,

```
y=40;
    b=Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2.25, 1.25}, {j, y - 5, y - 8, -3}], 1]
  c = b - ConstantArray[{0, 8}, 4]
d = c - ConstantArray[{0, 8}, 4]
e = d - ConstantArray[{0, 8}, 4]
f = e - ConstantArray[{0, 8}, 4]
```

and if any of the y limits (start and end) becomes less than 4, the occurance stops.

I tired nestlist and array but can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Most @ NestWhileList[# - Threaded[{0, 8}] &, b, Min @ #[[All, 2]] >= 4 &]
```

> ```
>  {{{1., 35}, {1., 32}, {2.25, 35}, {2.25, 32}}, 
>   {{1., 27}, {1., 24}, {2.25, 27}, {2.25, 24}},
>   {{1., 19}, {1., 16}, {2.25, 19}, {2.25, 16}},
>   {{1., 11}, {1., 8}, {2.25, 11}, {2.25, 8}}}
> ```

```
{b, c, d, e} == lists
```

> ```
> True
> ```